# GLua check between vectors

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I'm trying to create something in a game called Garry's Mod that uses Lua for addons.

Basically I need to check if the player's cursor has entered a specific area.

```
if _hitentity:GetClass() == "treasury" then
        draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 0, 60, 20, Color(255,255,255,255))
        if _hitpos == Vector(self:LocalToWorld(Vector(33, -6, 30)), self:LocalToWorldAngles(Angle(0,90,90))) then
            draw.RoundedBox(0, 0, 60, 20, 20, Color(0,0,0,255))
        end
    end
```

So I've basically got that, I check where the player's `hitpos` is (where he's looking) and `hitentity` (the entity he's looking at) and I need to check if he's looking at `draw.RoundedBox`.

Problem I'm having is I don't know how I could check if the cursor is inside a graphical box that is displayed on an entity.

This is the white box I need to check if the players hitpos has entered

[image]

Comment: Do you get the raw world coordinate or the coordinate in model space of the entity you're looking at? Expand on that.

Comment: What is the line where you compare hitpos to a point (Vector), is it how you are currently trying to determine if hitpoint is box? That cant work, where are you getting those numbers 33, -3, 30 from?

Answer (score -1):

This may be late to the Party but I can only recommend the usage of the [imgui library](https://github.com/wyozi-gmod/imgui/) It really makes the creation of buttons and displays easy.

If you don't want to use it, you can check how he did it.